# What's the meaning of `! [rejected] dev_tom -> dev_tom (non-fast-forward) * [new branch] dev_tom -> remote_repo/dev_tom`?

Tags: git

When I git pull the remote repo from branch `remote_repo/dev_tom` to my local repo `dev_top` branch:

```
dele-MBP:BK2 ldl$ git pull remote_repo dev_tom:dev_tom
dele@13.20.32.76's password: 
remote: counting: 45, complete.
remote: compressing: 100% (44/44), complete.
remote: Total 45 (delta 36), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (45/45), done.
From 13.20.32.76:/data/dele/repo/BK2
 ! [rejected]        dev_tom -> dev_tom  (non-fast-forward)
 * [new branch]      dev_tom -> remote_repo/dev_tom
```

you see there get two lines information, but I don't understand, distinctly, the pull action is fail:

```
! [rejected]        dev_tom -> dev_tom  (non-fast-forward)
* [new branch]      dev_tom -> remote_repo/dev_tom
```

What's the meaning of the two lines?

1. what's the meaning of `dev_tom -> dev_tom`?
2. what's the meaning of `dev_tom -> remote_repo/dev_tom`?
3. what's the meaning of `!`, `*`?
4. what's the meaning of `rejected`, `new branch`?  the `new branch` is not mean create a new branch, alright?
5. what's the meaning of `non-fast-forward`?

---

I use the `git fetch` still not work, there get `non-bare repository` error.

```
dele-MBP:BK2 ldl$ git fetch remote_repo dev_tom:dev_tom
ldl@13.20.32.76's password: 
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/dev_tom of non-bare repository
```

Comment: I'm guessing your local `dev_tom` has new commits, so the remote `dev_tom` can't be automatically merged. Maybe you need to checkout this branch first?

Comment: I was under the `dev_tom`.

Comment: Then just execute `git pull`. This automatically merges the branch(if merge conflicts occur, you will have to resolve them.

Comment: What's the difference between `git pull` and `git pull remote_repo dev_tom:dev_tom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you probably should not run:

> ```
> git pull remote_repo dev_tom:dev_tom
> ```

at all.  But that doesn't answer the question about what the various output lines mean, so let's look at that.  Note that this is kind of long, but it has to be, to be complete.

#### Pull means fetch+(merge|rebase), and fetch uses refspecs

First, remember that `git pull` really means *run two Git commands*.  The *first* of these two Git commands is always `git fetch`.  Most options and parameters to `git pull` go straight through to `git fetch`, so:

```
git fetch remote_repo dev_tom:dev_tom
```

does something extremely similar, and this explains all of the output lines.  So we'll concentrate here on what `git fetch` does, rather than worrying about `git pull` at all.  Instead, I'll just note that the point of the second command is to *integrate* something that `git fetch` brought in.  That is, this whole thing is a two-step process: *get some commits, then do something with the commits*.  The fetch step is the *get commits* part.<sup>1</sup>

The `git fetch` command calls up some other Git to get commits from that other Git.  Therefore, when you use `git fetch`, you must tell it several things:

- Where should it find the other Git?

  At the most basic level, you can give `git fetch` a URL for this:

  ```
  git fetch https://github.com/path/to/repo.git
  ```

  for instance.  URLs, however, are kind of long and hard to type correctly every time, so Git offers you a way to store a URL under a short name like `origin`.  This lets you run:

  ```
  git fetch origin
  ```

  or even just `git fetch`, which implies a remote—usually `origin`—based on the branch you have checked out.

  The URL is stored under the remote name:

  ```
  git config --get-all remote.origin.url
  ```

  (assuming the remote is named `origin`).
- What *branch names*, if any, are particularly interesting *in* the other Git?

  You don't have to name any.  If you don't, the default for Git is to consider *every* branch name that they have interesting.  This is actually controlled by a setting that you can observe:

  ```
  git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
  ```

  Note that this setting, too, is under the name of the remote (`origin` in this case).  So `origin` provides not only the URL, but also the default set of interesting branches.  (If you use a URL instead of a remote like `origin`, you miss out on this "default branches" feature.  So not only is `origin` shorter and easier to type correctly, it also gets you more features.)
- Finally, there's a problem with *just* getting *commits* from another Git repository.  Commits are numbered (or named) by their hash IDs.  You have seen hash IDs in `git log` output:

  ```
  commit 745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26
  Author: Junio C Hamano ...
  ```

  That big ugly string of letters and numbers, `745f681whatever`, is the ID of the commit.  These IDs seem totally random (though they're actually not) and there is no way to know which one is which.  This is really what branch names like `master`, and *remote-tracking* names like `origin/master`, are all about.

Let's take a closer look at the result of `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This string—`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`—has several parts:

- There is an optional leading plus sign `+`, which this one has.
- Then there are two strings separated by a colon `:`.  The colon is just barely optional: what's on the *left side* of the colon is the *source* part, and what's on the *right side* is the *destination* part.

Git calls this thing—the optional plus sign, then the source-colon-destination—a *refspec*.  The `fetch` command uses this refspec to control *which branches it looks at* when the other Git offers them, and what *names* it updates in *your* Git as a result.

Note that in this case, our source part is `refs/heads/*`:

- The `refs/heads/` part reveals something important about branch names: they're actually just a specific case of a more general Git mechanism.  The more general mechanism is called *refs* or *references*, and it includes tag names as well.  The *branch* `master` is actually `refs/heads/master`.  The *tag* `v2.1` is actually `refs/tags/v2.1`.<sup>2</sup>  Various Git commands leave off the front part, showing you just `master` or `v2.1`, when it's clear that it's a branch or tag name.
- The `*` part means *all names*.  Since the leading `refs/heads/` part selects just *branch* names, the `*` winds up meaning *all names that are branch names*.  So that's why our Git will default to looking at all of *their* Git's branches.

Our *destination* part is `refs/remotes/origin/*`:

- The `refs/remotes/` part refers to our *remote-tracking names*.  The next literal string, `origin/`, is just a literal `origin/`.
- The `*` means *whatever got matched by the source part*.

So this is how their branch `master`—their `refs/heads/master` ref—becomes our remote-tracking name `origin/master`, which is our `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  We took their `master`, and changed it to our `origin/master`, because of this fetch refspec.

A simple `git fetch origin` will therefore have our Git call up their Git, get a listing from them of all their branch names, and copy *all* of those names to our remote-tracking `origin/*` names.  Our Git's memory of their Git's branches will be updated.  This is also where the leading plus sign comes in: it is a *force flag*.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *second* command that `git pull` runs for you defaults to `git merge`, but you can choose `git rebase` instead.  Which one *should* you use?  That's up to you—but I'll note here that in some cases, you might want to decide based on what `git fetch` fetched.  If you use `git pull`, you're forced to decide which second command to use *before* you see what `git fetch` has fetched.  For this and many other reasons, I prefer not to use `git pull` at all.  Just run each of the two commands yourself, running `git log` *between* them when you want to make decisions about *which* command to use to finish the job.

<sup>2</sup>This means you can create a tag named `master`—`refs/tags/master`—which is different from the *branch* named master, `refs/heads/master`.  Don't do it!  It won't hurt *Git* but it will confuse the heck out of *you*. :-)

---

#### Names hold only one hash ID, but that means many commits

It's worth stopping here a moment and looking at how commits work in Git.

Every commit has its own unique hash ID, as we mentioned above.  That hash ID serves to *find* the commit, in the big Git database of "all the commits and other internal Git objects that you have in this repository".  Finding out whether a hash ID exists in the repository, and if so, what its contents are, is a quick database lookup operation.  What's actually *in* the commit, though, is really important.

Besides saving a full snapshot of all of your files (indirectly, through a *tree* object), each Git commit records some *metadata:* some information about the commit itself, that's not part of the files-snapshot.  This includes the author—name, email address, and date-and-time-stamp—of the commit, the same information about the *committer* (usually the same as the author), and of course whatever commit *log message* the author and committer recorded when they made the commit.  But it also includes some number of *parent* hash IDs, usually one.  The parent of a commit is the commit that comes *before* this particular commit.

In other words, when you have a branch name like `master`, it holds only one commit hash ID.  But that one hash ID finds an actual commit.  That commit has *another* hash ID: the hash of the commit that goes *before* it.  So if we have a branch name `master` holding some hash H:

```
        ... <-H   <-- master
```

we can use `H` to find `G`:

```
    ... <-G <-H   <-- master
```

and having found `G`, we can use that to find `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

and so on.  So a name like `master` identifies *one* commit, but that one commit eventually leads to *every* commit that comes before it, in a chain leading all the way back to the very first commit.

To add a *new* commit to a repository, Git:

- saves the snapshot
- adds you as author and committer, with "now" as the date/time
- puts in your log message
- puts in the *current* commit as the parent of the *new* commit

and hten uses all of that to make the commit object.  This commit object gets a new and unique hash ID—let's call it `I` for short—and puts that into the repository database:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

(`I`'s parent is `H`) and then, as its final step, *writes the new commit's hash ID into the **name** `master`:*

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

or:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

That's how branches grow.

Note that when this happens, all the commits that were reachable by starting at the end of the chain before—at `H`—and working backwards, are *still in the chain*.  We just now start at the *new* end, `I`, and work backwards.

Now, suppose that, by whatever means, your Git has suddenly acquired a bunch of new commits:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J--K--L
```

Your Git can "slide the name forward", in a sort of *fast-forward* operation (like fast-forwarding a tape recorder, for those who remember what a tape recorder is), against the internal backwards-pointing arrows:

```
...--F--G--H--I
               \
                J--K--L   <-- master
```

This kind of branch-name move is a *fast-forward* operation.

But what happens if, instead of `J` having `I` as its parent, `J` has `H` as its parent?  Then we start with:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
            \
             J--K--L
```

If we move `master` to point to `L`, what happens to commit `I`?

```
...--F--G--H--I
            \
             J--K--L   <-- master
```

The answer is: commit `I` just disappears.  We can't find it any more!  The internal arrows always go backwards, from the child commit to its parent.  There's no forward-arrow from `H` to `I`, only a backwards arrow from `I` to `H`.  So if we change `master` from remembering the hash of `I` to remembering the hash of `L`, we *lose* commit `I` entirely.  We end up with:

```
...--F--G--H--J--K--L   <-- master
```

Commit `I` is just gone.

#### Forcing remote-tracking name updates

Losing commits is, in Git's programming at least, a bad thing.  So to make Git do this, you must *force* the name-change.  That's what `--force` is about, and that's what the leading plus sign `+` on a *refspec* is.

Remote-tracking names are exactly like branch names in most ways.<sup>3</sup>  That includes Git's reluctance to modify them in ways that are not fast-forward operations.  That is, suppose you had:

```
             I   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

and you ran `git fetch origin` and that `fetch` brought in commits `J`, `K`, and `L` that are arranged this way:

```
             I   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             J--K--L
```

That `fetch` operation can now *fast-forward* `origin/master` so that it moves from `H` to `L`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
            \
             J--K--L   <-- origin/master
```

But if the new `J` has `G` as its parent, for some reason:

```
             I   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          J--K--L
```

then Git won't update `origin/master` from `H` to `L` unless you *force* the update.  The plus sign in:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

tells Git that it should force these updates if needed.  If you *leave out* the plus sign, Git will *reject* such an attempt.

---

<sup>3</sup>The key difference is that you can get "on" a branch name—`git status` will say `on branch master`—but you can't get "on" a remote-tracking name.  Doing `git checkout origin/master` gets you, instead, a *detached HEAD*.  Because the ability to be "on" it is the key feature of a branch, that makes remote-tracking names different from branch names.  But in all *other* ways, they're basically the same.

---

#### We can finally explain your output

You ran:

```
git fetch remote_repo dev_tom:dev_tom
```

The `remote_repo` part here is a remote name like `origin`.  The `dev_tom:dev_tom` part here is a *refspec*.  This refspec partly overrides, and partly *augments*, the refspec that Git will find when it runs:

```
git config --get-all remote.remote_repo.fetch
```

which presumably reads:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/remote_repo/*
```

If you used `--single-branch` or similar, it might have something else in it: perhaps multiple lines of output.  You could also have done `git config --edit` or otherwise messed with the setting, but this is probably how it's set.

Your Git now calls up the other Git at the URL from `git config --get remote.remote_repo.url`.  That Git offers a bunch of references, including `refs/heads/dev_tom`.  The reference has a hash ID.<sup>4</sup>  Your Git uses that hash ID to find out if you need to get new commits from their Git: do you have the commit that this hash ID specifies?  If not, you need to get it, and any other objects needed to complete a whole chain of commits that lead back to commits that you *do* have.

In this case, their `dev_tom` named some commit that was *not* a descendant of the tip of your own `dev_tom`.  It's impossible for me to know exactly what these commit chains looked like, but one possibility is:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- dev_tom
            \
             J--K--L   <-- [their dev_tom]
```

(Other possibilities include  that their `dev_tom` points to `H`, or `G`, or `F`, etc.)

If they had commits you didn't, your Git brought those commits in—`J`, `K`, and `L` in the example above.  Then your Git did two things, which we can cover in reverse:

1. Your Git obeyed the `fetch` refspec:

   ```
   +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/remote_repo/*
   ```

   This refspec says that their branches should be *renamed* to become your remote-tracking names.  So their `dev_tom` becomes your `remote_repo/dev_tom`.

   > ```
   >  * [new branch]      dev_tom -> remote_repo/dev_tom
   > ```

   Your `remote_repo/dev_tom` remote-tracking name is new to your repository, so your Git assumes that their `dev_tom` must not have existed in their repository before.  That makes their `dev_tom` a new branch in *their* Git.  Whether you have a `dev_tom` or not is irrelevant: your Git is only considering the fact that you *did not* have a `refs/remotes/remote_dev/dev_tom` reference.  (And now you do.)
2. Your command-line refspec was `dev_tom:dev_tom`.  This says *use their `dev_tom` to overwrite my `dev_tom`—or in this case, use their `refs/heads/dev_tom` to overwrite your `refs/heads/dev_tom`.<sup>5</sup>

   > ```
   >  ! [rejected]        dev_tom -> dev_tom  (non-fast-forward)
   > ```

   Using the hash ID from their `dev_tom` to overwrite *your* `dev_tom` branch name would cause your Git to lose some commit(s), such as commit `I`.  (Exactly which commits, depends on the graph, which you have not shown and we can only guess.)

   You did not use `--force`, nor use a plus sign (`+dev_tom:dev_tom`) so your Git refused to overwrite your own branch name with this hash ID.  In other words, your Git rejected a non-fast-forward update.

Note that there are two more possible `git fetch` outputs, which look like this (assuming a `git fetch origin`):

```
From <url>
   aaaaaaa..bbbbbbb  name1   -> origin/name1
 + ccccccc...ddddddd name2   -> origin/name2  (forced update)
```

The space-and-two-dots indicate that you had `origin/name1` before.  Its hash ID before was, abbreviated, `aaaaaaa`.  It is now `bbbbbbb` and this update was a fast-forward.

The plus-sign, three-dots, and `(forced update)` annotations indicate that you had `origin/name2` before.  Its hash ID before was `ccccccc` (abbreviated) and is now `ddddddd`; this update was a non-fast-forward, but was done anyway due to the force flag.

The four one-letter codes are: space (existing remote-tracking name and fast-forward update), `*` (new remote-tracking name), `+` (existing remote-tracking name and forced non-fast-forward update), and `!` (existing remote-tracking anme and error updating it; the exact error is usually `non-fast-forward` but other errors are possible).

---

<sup>4</sup>To see these, run:

```
git ls-remote remote_repo
```

This is like `git fetch` in that it calls up the other Git.  However, unlike `git fetch`, it doesn't take refspecs and does not bring over commits.  It just calls up that Git and then dumps, to its output (your terminal window), the information that the other Git provides.

<sup>5</sup>These are *unqualified* reference names: your Git will guess, based on various things in your and their reference name spaces, whether to use branch names or tag names or whatever.  In this case your Git guessed that these were both to be treated as branch names.